# Digital Metaphors: Report Builder - How to iterate through datasource elements?

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I'm working with ReportBuilder 12.05 and I'm trying to iterate through an array (I guess) of my datasource.

I've got a datasource called "STAFF" with some fields within - dynamically created from a database table.

So the table look like this:

```
tablename: STAFF
id | name | last_name
----------------------
1  | Alex | Gates
2  | Pete | Jefferson
...
```

I can access a single element by accessing `STAFF['LAST_NAME']`. But this will always post "**Gates**" as a result. How do I iterate through all my `STAFF`?

My code currently looks like this:

```
memo1.lines.clear;
for len := 1 to 5 do
begin
    memo1.lines.add(STAFF['LAST_NAME'])
end;
```

Comment: `Error: SummaryBeforePrint, row 5: Expecting: '(' or '[', got 'Next' instead.`

Comment: AFAIK it isn't a function. I'm totaly new to this tool.

Comment: If I write it without `Staff.Next` it works - saying: it runs into an endless loop. So, but when I add `.Next` it will not work at all. :(

Comment: 12.05, Build 251, Enterprise Edition // Yes, it is within the BeforePrint event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41863/discussion-between-init3-and-matheus-freitas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a SubReport to the summary band, then select the new SubReport tab at the bottom of the designer, set it to have multiple columns and to column traversal left to right (File->Page Setup->Layout), then assign the datapipeline to the SubReport.  Then add your fields to the SubReport.

Answer (score 0):

OP was using end-user scripting engine. 
So it may necessary to change the event to reach what he wants:

According to Help:

> Declaration
>
> property OnEndPage: TNotifyEvent;
>
> This event fires after a page has completed printing. If you set
>   DonePrinting to True in this event handler, no further pages will
>   print.

This event should be used instead of BeforePrint.